# Load a CSV file using PDO results in a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I need to load 100+ CSV files into MySQL, so I'm writing a script to do this. Among other things, I have the following snippet, which imports each CSV file:

```
    private function importFile(){
    if($this->connection->beginTransaction()){
        $transactionFailed = false;
        $importStatement = $this->connection->prepare("
            LOAD DATA INFILE :file
            REPLACE INTO TABLE :table;
        ");
        foreach($this->fetchFileList() as $file){
            $executeSuccesfull = $importStatement->execute(array(
                ':file' => $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file,
                ':table' => $file
            ));
            if(!$executeSuccesfull){
                $transactionFailed = true;
                $this->fetchDBError($importStatement);
                $this->connection->rollBack();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$transactionFailed){
            $this->connection->commit();
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->fetchDBError();
    }
}
```

`$this->path` points to the path where all CSV files are located (and I checked that). Each `$file` has the exact same name as the table where it's data should be imported, without file extension (no `.csv` in any of them). I'm using PHP 5.3.9, MySQL 5.0.27 running on top of a Windows XP. All of that runs in my local machine.

The problem is, I'm geting the following error:

```
[ERROR 42000] — You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''the_first_file'' at line 2 (1064)

The query issued was:

            LOAD DATA INFILE :file
            REPLACE INTO TABLE :table;
```

This code was generated by another method of my class:

```
    private function fetchDBError($statement = null){
    $errorCode = null;
    $errorInfo = null;
    $queryString = '';
    if($statement){
        $errorInfo = $statement->errorInfo();
        $errorCode = $statement->errorCode();
        $queryString = "<p>The query issued was:</p><pre>{$statement->queryString}</pre>";
    }
    else{
        $errorInfo = $this->connection->errorInfo();
        $errorCode = $this->connection->errorCode();
    }
    $this->success = false;
    $this->message = "<p>[ERROR $errorCode] {$errorInfor[0]} &mdash; {$errorInfo[2]} ({$errorInfo[1]})</p>$queryString";
```

Answer (score 0):

One or more files contains aphostophe, try to use this:

```
      $filepath = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  str_replace("'", "''", $file);
```

And then use $filepath in the query parameter.

This is an example of the mysql load data function:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filepath' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Also try to specify  FIELDS TERMINATED BY.

In a stackoverflow post, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533151/php-load-data-infile-syntax-errors)  about prepare function and LOAD DATA.

Comment: Still the same thing. The first file do not have any apostrophes, and no file name have it either.

Comment: Still no changes. I tried to put `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'`, which matches my CSV files format, but got no improvements.

Comment: Try to add single quote after and before the parameter :file (':file')

Comment: PDO fills all the single quotes in prepared statements, so it renders an error when you try to insert them manually. I tried it anyway: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: Try to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533151/php-load-data-infile-syntax-errors

Comment: I've found that same question before. It addresses an issue different from what I have.